The big prefix L has no effect in %Lf, the result in printf() is same as just %f
Currently learning about C language, I repeated after guy in tutorial, he used printf("value = %Lf\n", var_some); construction to output the value of long double variable, and it worked.
But when I repeated the same, it returns some unexpected very long negative number. If I run code without L, it returns exactly the same, like 'L' gives no effect.
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{   
    long double var_some = 123456221312.2132323213123121;
    printf("value = %Lf\n", var_some);
    return 0;
} 

If I make this variable simple double without 'long', then it works fine , even if I add 'L'.
I am using gcc compiler.

Note that MS VC gives the correct (only to 4 places) output for the code shown. It implements long double as double. It isn't clear what is meant by "when I repeated the same" or what is meant by "returns". Function printf() returns the number of characters printed, or a negative value if an error occurs.
